# Data source for aws_vpc_endpoint_service_allowed_principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to check the list of `aws_vpc_endpoint_service_allowed_principal` from a specific `aws_vpc_endpoint_service`.

The `aws_vpc_endpoint_service` data source does not return the list of `allowed_principals`.

Does anyone know how can I retrieve that information?

Comment: Besides stating the obvious of referencing the resource attribute, I am guessing this is needed elsewhere? If you could give an example of the code you have and say where and how you plan on using it, there might be a way to answer.

Comment: We have a endpoint_service with allowed_principals for multiple different accounts. Basically I need to check if the current account has already been allowed or not and proceed with that information.

Comment: Proceed where? You need it as an output? As you mention data source, do you need it in another module? Another account?

Comment: If an allowed_principal has been created previous (by hand), terraform won't do anything.
If it has not been added, it will add it.

Comment: Sorry, context is lacking. Without an example of the code in the question, it's really hard to tell what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data source for that resource does not exist, you can use [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) with a custom script to query the required information.

Here's an example script (`get_vpc_endpoint_service_permissions.sh`) that fetches the required information:

```
#!/bin/bash
sep=$(aws ec2 describe-vpc-endpoint-service-permissions --service-id vpce-svc-03d5ebb7d9579a2b3 --query 'AllowedPrincipals')
jq -n --arg sep "$sep" '{"sep":$sep}'
```

and here's how you consume it in terraform:

```
data "external" "vpc_endpoint_service_permissions" {
  program = ["bash", "get_vpc_endpoint_service_permissions.sh"]
}

output "vpc_endpoint_service_permissions" {
  value = data.external.vpc_endpoint_service_permissions.result.sep
}
```

`data.external.vpc_endpoint_service_permissions.result.sep` contains the output of the bash script, which is a JSON array that you can access/manipulate as needed.

Comment: Thank you! this is a really good idea. I haven't used external data sources before.

Comment: @Leo You're welcome. I use them whenever I need to query something that isn't supported by a certain data source, or when the data source doesn't exist altogether